# Change color attributes everyday on my Tumblr Theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want everyday, the color background and text (caption+title) to invert from black to white. I know it can be done with Java.

Here is my Tumblr page: http://recherches.nicolaspauly.com

Comment: First things first, Java is very different from Java*script*.  Welcome to Stackoverflow - we love to help, but we don't like just doing things for people.  If you can provide some code with things you've tried, we can work from there!

Answer (score 2):

You can use some JavaScript on the client to get the day and based on this add a certain class to the `body` or parent element of your choice.

It will look something like this (using jQuery for simplicity):

```
var d = new Date(),
    styleType = d.getDay()%2, //Returns the day of the week (0-6), mod can be changed accordingly based on number of different "themes" you want to support
    //this is a setup for 2 different themes
    $body = $('body');

if(styleType === 0){
  $body.addClass('inverted');
} else {
  $body.addClass('not-inverted');
}
```

You can use these classes now to specify CSS selectors to get the styles you want for example:

```
body.inverted .someClass {
  background: white;
}

body.not-inverted .someClass {
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks.

So i don't need to stylise <body> right ?

Comment: @nicolaspauly no you don't need to add styles to `body` unless you want to. The example I gave simply used `body`  to add the specific class since it's usually a high enough parent element that most elements will be inside body.

Comment: @nicolaspauly are you loading the jQuery library and using `$` to represent the window.jQuery object?

Comment: Is it good if I do it like this ?


    <script src="http://static.tumblr.com/fjuuplb/iPKmxnkr3/jquery.min.js">
    var d = new Date(),
    styleType = d.getDay()%2, 
    $body = $('body');
            
    if(styleType === 0){
    $body.addClass('inverted');
    } else {
    $body.addClass('not-inverted');
    }
    </script>

Comment: @nicolaspauly Take a look at the [script documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) You aren't allowed to have content within script tags that have `src` attribute. If you include 2 separate script tags it will work. One for jQuery and one for your own custom script.